# Class name and value selection in xpath

Tags: xpath

I am new to x path and I am having a hard time resolving the following issue.

I am trying to access the below element `<div class="MeCalendarMonthName">Aug 2013</div>` using the below approach.

```
xpath=//div[@class='MeCalendarMonthName' and @value='Aug 2013']
```

and also I tried

```
(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Aug 2013']").
```

But, I am failing with both approaches.

MeCalendarMonthName is a common class which is repeated many times in the tree, therefore I tried to use the combination of class name and value and tried to find only with the value. Can you please help me to find a suitable solution?

Comment: Your expression `(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Aug 2013']")` lacks a `)`, did you notice that?

Comment: Your second expression should be fine. Are you sure the element does exactly look like the one posted here? Watch out for other content of the div, and also trailing whitespace. Is there any namespace in the document?

Comment: Hi , Yes, This is how it looks <div class="MeCalendarMonthName">Aug 2013</div>. I just copied the tree path.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below approach :

```
 //div[@class='MeCalendarMonthName' and contains(.='Aug 2013')]
```

As per your comment you can use the below xpath:

```
 //input[@value = 'Tue Aug 13 2013']
```

when the HTML

```
 <input type="hidden" value="Tue Aug 13 2013">
```

Comment: Hi Rakshit, Thanks for responding. However the script is failing as its not able to recognise the command/element. I tried this approach (By.xpath("//[@type='hidden']/@Tue Sep 13 2013")) but still its failing to recognise the element.Here is the tree structure <input type="hidden" value="Tue Aug 13 2013">

Answer (score 0):

```
xpath("//div[contains(.,'Aug 2013')]")
```

Comment: Hi , Thank you very much for responding.For some reason the script fails when I run my script on a different browser. However I tried this approach (By.xpath("//[@type='hidden']/@Tue Sep 13 2013")).click(); but getting error , unable to find the path. Here is the tree structure <input type="hidden" value="Tue Aug 13 2013">

Comment: try `xpath("//input[@value = 'Tue Aug 13 2013']")`